# Examples of group extension $G/N=Q$ with continuous $G$ and $N$, but finite $Q$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, lie-groups, spectral-sequences

Can we have some examples of group extensions $G/N=Q$ with continuous (e.g. topological groups or Lie groups) $G$ and $N$, but a finite discrete $Q$? Note that $1 \to N \to G \to Q \to 1$.

What else are the examples that you can provide?

A systematic answer to obtain new examples (a few or even a list) is of course most welcome. ; )

Another related questions: What I know already knew are some examples of continuous (e.g. Lie groups) $G$ and $Q$, but a finite discrete $N$ [here (but I am looking for more examples  there, too --- because the examples there are only two)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209703).

Comment: There is a very uninformative way to produce examples, namely taking $N$ to be whatever you like, $Q$ any finite group, and $G= N \times Q$. The simplest "naturally occuring" example I can think of is $G=O(n)$, $N=SO(n)$, and $Q = \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 4):

Just choose an open, normal subgroup of a compact group, eg.

> $$1\to p\Bbb Z_p\to \Bbb Z_p\to \Bbb Z/p\to 1$$

So long as the upstairs group is Hausdorff, the open subgroups are exactly the closed subgroups of finite index, so you pick any abelian group and you're good to go.

You can do similarly with $p$-adic units, eg

$$1\to 1+p\Bbb Z_p\to \Bbb Z_p^\times\to (\Bbb Z/p)^\times\to 1$$

or

$$1\to 1+p^2\Bbb Z_p\to 1+p\Bbb Z_p\to \Bbb Z/p\to 1$$

or if you prefer something a bit more exotic, do the same with polynomial or power series rings eg.

$$1\to \langle p(t)\rangle\to \Bbb F_p[t]\to \Bbb F_p(\alpha)\to 1$$

for any irreducible $p(t)\in \Bbb F_p[t]$ and $\alpha$ a root.

Comment: Another well known example of what Adam describes is $1\rightarrow SO(n)\rightarrow O(n)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Yes, as @JasonDeVito says, it's a fantastic way to generate large lists!

Comment: And at least for compact Lie groups, it's the *only* way to generate such lists!  That is, given $1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 1$ with $Q$ discrete, $N$ must be open and normal.

Comment: Thanks, +1, is there restriction whether $G, N, Q$ are compact or not?

Comment: @annieheart not really no, you only **need** finite index and normal, the point is that in the compact case this is equivalent to open and normal (since of course you want closed subgroups and hausdorff as usual)